# How to make a text-heavy table in a two-column document?

Tags: tables, two-column, article

I've been trying to insert a table, that is essentially quite simple, into a two-column document. It has been throwing up all sorts of warnings (most perplexingly: `Missing number, treated as zero` for the `begin{tabular*}` line.

I would like it to look like a simple cross-shaped table, but inserting `\hline`s makes the whole thing crash. What happens with this code (see the example below) is that the table floats off the right side of the page, the `{p|p}` is shown on the left side of the table (which does not happen if I replace that with `{c|c}`), and the ampersands don't appear to be recognised as the column change.

The table should not take any notice of the two-columness of the rest of the doc, which is why the `*`s are added, I believe.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{dblfloatfix} % floats in twocolumns come out in the right order

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}[t]
    \caption{problematic table}
    \label{tab:ohNo}
    \begin{tabular*}{p|p} 
    Title 1 & Title 2 \\
    there is no definitive formulation of a wicked problem & Energy efficiency can be framed as a techno-economic problem, or a problem related to fundamental issues as lifestyle and such. \\ 
    wicked problems have no stopping rule & Energy efficiency is a continuous process and must be related to many different factors such as cost efficiency and employees health and safety. 
    \end{tabular*}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! You have to specify the widths of the `p ` columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Environment `tabular*` require specification for table width. In your case something like `\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{<column specification>}`
- Column `p` had to have defined width. For example `p{0.45\linewidth}`
- It seems, that  package `tabularx` with `X` columns type which width determine LaTeX) solve your problem on the simplest way:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}[t]
    \caption{problematic table}
    \label{tab:ohNo}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{X|X}
    Title 1 & Title 2 \\
there is no definitive formulation of a wicked problem  
            & Energy efficiency can be framed as a techno-economic problem, or a problem related to fundamental issues as lifestyle and such. \\
wicked problems have no stopping rule 
            & Energy efficiency is a continuous process and must be related to many different factors such as cost efficiency and employees health and safety.
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

[image]